# Importing Polymer Elements in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, polymer, assetic

I was doing some research about WebComponents. Till now I was using only Polymer (in Dart or Javascript) and I started thinking about using it in my Symfony2 project.
My question is: **How do you handle importing Polymer elements resources into Symfony2?** Do you use some kind of Assetic filter? Is it even possible with Assetic?
The thing is there is a need to import a single element like

```html
<link rel="import" 
      href="bower_components/polymer-elements/core-ajax/core-ajax.html />
```

To include 100 components it can be quite exhausting and less readable. Is there any other way to import them more naturally? Like Assetic always does in Symfony2, in YAML config files?